# VirtualBox guest additions update got error missing SELinux target policy file

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux, selinux, guest-additions

While updating VirtualBox guest additions on a Red Hat Linux 7 (RHEL7) virtual machine, we got the below error about missing a target policy file of SELinux.

We checked the virtual machine:

- We tried the command `yum install selinux-policy-targeted` following [this post](https://dbalifeeasy.com/2020/09/14/error-unable-to-open-policy-etc-selinux-targeted-policy-policy-31/), but the package had been installed already.
- The alerting file exists; however, its size is zero.
- We disabled SELinux on this virtual machine a long time ago.

So, we wonder whether the error affects the guest additions and if we can resolve the error. We appreciate hints and suggestions.

**Partial terminal output:**

```
... omitting ...

[root@hostname ~]# yum install selinux-policy-targeted
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-268.el7_9.2.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@hostname ~]#

... omitting ...

[root@hostname ~]# ll //etc/selinux/targeted/policy/policy.31
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun  6 13:33 //etc/selinux/targeted/policy/policy.31

... omitting ...

[root@hostname ~]# sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 6.1.34 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 6.1.34 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel
3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64.
ERROR: Can't map '//etc/selinux/targeted/policy/policy.31':  Invalid argument

ERROR: Unable to open policy //etc/selinux/targeted/policy/policy.31.
libsemanage.semanage_read_policydb: Error while reading kernel policy from /etc/selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern. (No such file or directory).
OSError: No such file or directory
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until
the system is restarted
[root@hostname ~]# reboot now
Connection to hostname closed by remote host.
Connection to hostname closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling selinux-policy-targeted:
`sudo yum remove selinux-policy-targeted`
`sudo yum install selinux-policy-targeted`

Re-run Guest Additions:
`sudo /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Finally, reboot your system to replace the kernel modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).